# error messages when enabling /server-status on Centos with Apache version httpd-2.2.3-31

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, httpd

I enabled the following on httpd.conf:

**ExtendedStatus On**

**LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so**

and also:

---

NameVirtualHost *:80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myserver.com
  ServerAlias myserver.com 

  DocumentRoot /prod/html

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*myserver.com$
  RewriteRule /(.*) http://myserver.com/$1 [R,L]





**<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
</Location>**

</VirtualHost>
```

when running **`lynx http://localhost/server-status`**  get the following message:
**You don't have permission to access /server-status on this server.**

I don't see anything related to /server-status in my /etc/httpd folder
these are the folders I have under /etc/httpd:

```
**conf
conf.d
logs -> ../../var/log/httpd
modules -> ../../usr/lib/httpd/modules
run -> ../../var/run**
```

any idea why I get the **"permission denied"** error?
do I need to install another package for get it?
Thanks!!
Dotan.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with VirtualHosts' configuration. It's hard to say without looking at full dump of Apache configuration. Did you restart Apache? Is there anything in ErrorLog?

Comment: This is the error I get: [Thu Dec 27 20:05:17 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /prod/html/server-status

Comment: here is my httpd.conf:

Comment: Try adding `ServerAlias localhost` to this VirtualHost declaration. Try `lynx http://myserver.com/server-status`. Try temporary disabling mod_rewrite. As @Epaphus suggested try moving server-status declaration outside VirtualHost. Do you have any other VirtualHosts configured?

Comment: I added **ServerAlias localhost** and disabled the mod_rewrite but still I get **[error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /prod/html/server-status**

Comment: Change `Allow from localhost` to `Allow from 127.0.0.1`, restart Apache and try again. It has worked on my test server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with the IP instead of the host name, This is how mine looks ( ::1 is there as the server also has IPv6 enabled)

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
</Location>
```

Using

```
lynx http://localhost/server-status
```

might not be matching the virtual host "myserver.com" so you could try putting the Location /server-status outside of the VirtualHost in the http.conf

Answer (score 3):

Just in case this helps someone:

In newer versions of Apache there is a default server-status config setting in **conf/extra/httpd-info.conf** which will override any server-status settings in
**httpd.conf**

That default config in conf/extra/httpd-info.conf is set to “Allow from .example.com” and will annihilate all fancy server-status changes you do in httpd.conf

So if you are facing permission issues make sure you are editing the proper file!

Comment: How new of Apache version? And how do you know that this isn't something peculiar to your distribution (which you forgot to mention)?

Comment: I've been searching all over for an answer but this was it. Thank you so much! It was being overridden by (for me, on Debian) `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/status.conf`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at your ***/etc/hosts***

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I checked the /etc/hosts and found out that I have 2 hostnames listed for localhost:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
```

It seems some weird behavior between apache and the resolver.
If the first 127.0.0.1 entry is localhost.localdomain you should have it in apache config:

```
Allow from localhost.localdomain
```

then you can get the proper answer with both

```
curl localhost/server-status
curl localhost.localdomain/server-status
curl 127.0.0.1/server-status
```

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into a similar issue while trying to enable the status page for an Apache web server running in Kubernetes.

This was the image that I have been working with: `registry.k8s.io/hpa-example`, equipped with `Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) PHP/5.6.14`.

### Solution

I've simply created a custom config file (`/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/my-custom-config.conf`) with the following contents

```
<Location "/server-status">
  SetHandler server-status
  Require all granted
</Location>
```

and passed it to the Pod as a Volume. **Note**: This configuration is not not be used in production as Apache will allow any caller to view the status page. This was OK for my testing purposes.

---

This was the deployment yaml that I ended up using:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: apache-config
data:
  my-custom-config.conf: |
    <Location "/server-status">
      SetHandler server-status
      Require all granted
    </Location>

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php-apache
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: php-apache
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: php-apache
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: php-apache
        image: registry.k8s.io/hpa-example
        volumeMounts:
        - name: apache-config
          mountPath: /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      volumes:
      - name: apache-config
        configMap:
          name: apache-config

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: php-apache
  labels:
    run: php-apache
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    run: php-apache
```

This is how I've ran the server:

```bash
kubectl apply -f <path_to_the_deployment_yaml>
```

This is how I've tested the status page:

```bash
kubectl run -i --tty test-pod --rm --image=busybox:1.28 \
  --restart=Never -- /bin/sh -c "wget -O- http://php-apache/server-status"
```